# Why Codemirror editor does NOT scroll horizontally with long line?

Tags: css, codemirror

I've a code mirror version: 5.65.3 with Blazor. When I've a long line in the editor the horizontal scroll doesn't work, it rather uses the scroll of the page which mess out the whole page.

Like this:
[image]

I don't think that I changed any CSS in Codemirror.

Here is some related CSS lines:

```
    .CodeMirror {
  /* Set height, width, borders, and global font properties here */
  font-family: monospace;
  height: 750px;
  color: black;
  direction: ltr;

}


.CodeMirror-scroll {
  overflow: scroll !important; /* Things will break if this is overridden */
  /* 50px is the magic margin used to hide the element's real scrollbars */
  /* See overflow: hidden in .CodeMirror */
  margin-bottom: -50px; margin-right: -50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  outline: none; /* Prevent dragging from highlighting the element */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

I'm calling the codemirror through this code: (the onchange is because I'm using Blazor for binding purposes )

```
window.editor= function (dontNetObjRef) {

    editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('myTextArea'), {
        lineNumbers: true,
        indentUnit: 4,
        lineWrapping: true,
        tabMode: "shift",
        gutters: ["CodeMirror-lint-markers"]
    });

    //JavaScript function use the onchange event of CodeMirror to invoke the C# method and pass the value of the myTextArea .

    editor.on("change", editor => {
        dontNetObjRef.invokeMethodAsync("UpdateField", editor.getValue());
        // console.log(editor.getValue());

    });
```

Note: even if I used `lineWrapping: true` it moved to the second line and does the same issue with scroll.
Also, it works well when I set a fixed width like 1000px but I'd like to make it auto in case the screen size of the user changes.

Comment: Did you try to set `max-width`?

Comment: @Jax-p i've tried max-width:auto and 100% but no luck

Comment: Can you provide minimal reproducible example? Because [default setup works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/jaxpcze/95om6zyb/6/).

Comment: @Jax-p i've added more code - do you think that this is because I'm using Blazor?

Comment: I don't think so - it looks like CSS issue. Isn't CodeMirror wrapped in flex? I would make block (not flex) element as a parent and tried to use `max-width: 100vw` or something like that but it's just guessing as long as I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Jax-p When I've added the ' max-width: 100vw' it works if I've a long line with spaces like aaa bbb ccc ddd - but if I have a long word like aaabbbcccddd not working. i don't know if that's give you any hint about the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245939/discussion-between-fadi-akkad-and-jax-p).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jax-p for giving me some hints to fix the issue.

I've add `width:70vw` in `.CodeMirror` class and `max-width:70vw` in `.CodeMirror-scroll`

Another thing that was affecting the changes is that I was putting the textarea in inside a `<div class=col-11>` which was affecting the width in the CSS so I just removed that and everything is working.

Comment: Should `max-width:70vm` be `max-width:70vw` here?

Answer (score 2):

While working on a project I've encountered the same issue - that is a problem with CSS.

I fixed it with that pretty simple **flexbox** solution:

```
<div class="root-wrapper">                <!-- Editor parent container -->
    <div class="cm-editor ͼ1 ͼ2 ͼ4">      <!-- CodeMirror stuff (v6 in my case) -->
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

The corresponding styling:

```
.root-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;

    .cm-editor {
        width: 0;
        flex-grow: 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent fix. Works like a charm. I used it with the @uiw/react-codemirror component.